# Server-side render a modal in React upon clicking a button for NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I would like to server-side render a modal in ReactJS upon clicking a button. You can see an example on Product Hunt's website:

https://www.producthunt.com/

If you click on one of the popular products, it opens a modal, and then the page is rendered as a normal request on the server-side.

I'm not very good with React, but could someone point me in the right direction or show a code example?

I'm thinking I could prefetch the page upon someone clicking the link that activates the modal, then display the fetched content within the modal: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/with-prefetching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the product modals on producthunt are server-rendered. When you click on a product it opens the modal and then loads the data client side. Along with this operation, the also update the URL using `history`. Now if you refresh the page it would render a different view. You may implement this with `next` by having two different views in a similar fashion. For example you could create two pages in the `pages` directory, say:

```
pages
|- homepage.js
|- product.js
```

Then in your server configuration you can route all the requests starting from `/product` to render `product.js`. Modal logic can stay in `homepage.js` where you would render the appropriate modal when clicking on a product. Also you can push the url to history when you open the modal.

Now if the page is refreshed or a new browser tab/window opens with the same url it would ask the server to render `product.js`.

Comment: Really? I watched the network console in my browser and didn't see a different request pop up when I clicked on  a product. So I figured it was server-rendered.

Comment: I just checked and it sends a new request to `https://www.producthunt.com/frontend/graphql` api. I'm using firefox dev tools. Not sure why it didn't appear on your browser. Could you check if you're at the 'all' requests tab?

Comment: You are totally right .. was going crazy figuring out what they were doing (as it seems pretty ingenious) .. Thanks!